# Getting an error number is required message when I save the Custom function for Crystal Reports using VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I need to create a Custom function in Crystal Reports version 2010.
Below is the code.
I keep getting an error "Number is required" when I save the function using Field Explorer in  Visual Studio 2012.
 It highlights this piece of code : ret := ret + fchar;

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Do I have any syntax issues that I can correct.

The Custom Function I have created is given below:

Function (StringVar rollNo, StringVar rollNoFormat)

```
Local NumberVAR  pos := Length(rollNoFormat);
Local NumberVAR xpos := Length(rollNo);
Local StringVAR ret := "";
 Local StringVAR fchar := "";
```

While pos > 0 Do
    (

```
    fchar := Mid(rollNoFormat, pos, 1);
    If (fchar = "X") 
    Then
    (
        ret := ret + Mid(rollNo, xpos, 1);
        xpos := xpos - 1;       
    )
    Else
    (
        ret := ret + fchar;
    )

    pos := pos - 1;
);

If (Length(rollNoFormat) = 0 )
Then
( 
   ret := rollNo;
) 
Else
( 
 ret := StrReverse(ret);
)
```

ret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to add a number (pos) to a string when you declare fchar. Try to convert pos to a string: `Local NumberVAR  pos := Val(Length(rollNoFormat));` or something to that effect. Basically you are mixing string and number, so convert either one to have a match.

Hope that helps,

Chris

EDIT:

I tried to reproduce the formula, using 2 string fields. I ended up getting a different error than you which had to do with the parentheses. Here is the code that worked for me with rollno and rollnoFormat substitutes:

```
Local NumberVAR  pos := Length(immaster.prodclass);
Local NumberVAR xpos := Length(immaster.itemtype);
Local StringVAR ret := "";
Local StringVAR fchar := "";
While pos > 0 Do (

fchar := Mid(rollNoFormat, pos, 1);
If (fchar = "X") 
Then
(
ret := ret + Mid(rollNo, xpos, 1);
xpos := xpos - 1;       
)
Else
(
ret := ret + fchar;    
pos := pos - 1;
));
```

I moved the pos := pos - 1 after the ELSE into the parentheses and got no errors. So either that was the error or the value of either rollno or rollnoformat are not string.

Comment: @Chris : Not working. I believe Length is of the type NumberVar. Can you think of something else.

Comment: Now, I may be reading this wrong, but when you declare your fchar, you are using MID, but starting at the last letter (pos := Length(rollNoFormat)) and then asking for the last letter? You could make it easier and just use the RIGHT(rollnoformat, 1, 1). That way you wouldn't need pos and xpos and maybe that makes it a little cleaner.

Comment: I wanted to clarify I meant that Length takes in a type StringVar and returns a NumberVar.  Eg:  NumberVAR variable = Len(StringVAR) hence we do not need to do any conversion as you indicated. I would like you to tell me if any of my constructs/syntax in the satetements above are incorrect. Eg IF THEN ELSE with parantheses, etc or whatever you think could be wrong. I appreciate you helping me in advance. Let me know please.